# Correctly configure Celery to retry tasks working

Tags: python, django, celery

I've got a simple celery task like this:

```
@app.task(bind=True)
def dumb_task(self):
    print "DUMB to sleep"
    time.sleep(10)
    print "DUMB awakes"
    self.retry(max_retries=10000, countdown=15)
```

And I get a sucessful retry exception in 15s in the traceback of the task. But when the 15 seconds are elapsed, no task is executed. I've tried so many things that I'm super lost.

Here's the log of the Celery worker, if there's some chance to get what's going on:

```
[2015-01-20 13:42:03,332: WARNING/Worker-4:2] DUMB awakes
[2015-01-20 13:42:03,347: DEBUG/Worker-4:2] Start from server, version: 0.9, properties: {u'information': u'Licensed under the MPL.  See http://www.rabbitmq.com/', u'product': u'RabbitMQ', u'copyright': u'Copyright (C) 2007-2012 VMware, Inc.', u'capabilities': {u'exchange_exchange_bindings': True, u'consumer_cancel_notify': True, u'publisher_confirms': True, u'basic.nack': True}, u'platform': u'Erlang/OTP', u'version': u'2.8.4'}, mechanisms: [u'PLAIN', u'AMQPLAIN'], locales: [u'en_US']
[2015-01-20 13:42:03,348: DEBUG/Worker-4:2] Open OK!
[2015-01-20 13:42:03,348: DEBUG/Worker-4:2] using channel_id: 1
[2015-01-20 13:42:03,349: DEBUG/Worker-4:2] Channel open
[2015-01-20 13:42:03,355: INFO/Worker-4] Task gui.tasks.dumb_task[806d7cbf5d00-4886-a715-e15fd9038b85] retry: Retry in 15s
[2015-01-20 13:42:03,356: INFO/Worker-3] Received task: gui.tasks.dumb_task[806d7cbf-5d00-4886-a715-e15fd9038b85] eta:[2015-01-20 13:42:18.334884+01:00]
```

And the Celery Flower traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 240, in trace_task
R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 437, in __protected_call__
return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/revuelta/web/piar/web/gui/tasks.py", line 59, in dumb_task
self.retry(max_retries=10000, countdown=15)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/app/task.py", line 680, in retry
raise ret
Retry: Retry in 15s
```

But when the time is elapsed, no task is retried.

I'm thinkg that the problem might be in the timezones used by the system and Celery...

```
TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Madrid'
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'Europe/Madrid'
```

And date command in Debian shows up the next:

```
mar ene 20 13:49:25 CET 2015
```

Which is the same TZ from the logs.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `raise dumb_task.retry(countdown=15)`?

Comment: I've tried it with no change, raise forces the code to not execute if there was lines after the retry call, but makes no change in the retry call execution.

Comment: @AntonisChristofides `retry` method already raises, you don't need the `raise` in front except for code aesthetics

Comment: Could it be you're working in your dev environment and you have `CELERY_TASK_ALWAYS_EAGER = True` and `CELERY_TASK_EAGER_PROPAGATES = True`?

Answer (score 0):

we are using task retying in this way and is working properly:

```
@app.task
def fetch_followers(*args, **kwargs):
    try:
        # do some stuff here
    except RateLimitError as e:
        fetch_followers.retry(countdown=60)
        return False
```

Note that we are executing the `.retry()` explicitely using the task name `fetch_followers` instead of `self`. I'm not sure if it's the reason, but maybe it helps.

Another possibility would be that the task is raising some timeout before the `.retry()` is actually being executed, and that's why the new task is not queued.

BTW, which broker are you using? Are you able to see if a new task is queued in the broker when the timeout is reached?

I hope it helps.

Comment: when a task is binded to an app, you can use self term to retry itself, but if I do you way putting `dumb_task.retry(...)` it's the same, the task is received by a worker (as shown in the log of the worker) but it's never executed. Also, it's not necesary the retry to be in a except clause. I'm using RabbitMQ as a broker, but I don't have a way to see if the message is queued because seeing a message in MQTT consumes it...

Comment: Just stop the worker that is consuming from the queue (so the task is not immediately consumed) and check the RabbitMQ dashboard. You should be one task queued there.

Comment: You can also use `rabbitmqctl list_queues` in the terminal if you don't have the dashboard configured.

Comment: doesn't `[2015-01-20 13:42:03,356: INFO/Worker-3] Received task: gui.tasks.dumb_task[806d7cbf-5d00-4886-a715-e15fd9038b85] eta:[2015-01-20 13:42:18.334884+01:00]` mean the worker received the message from the queue?